# How to store simple static predefined data in Android

Tags: java, android, store

Here is the thing; I have to store simple data which I have to define once (manually). I must have a functionality to search in it after using keywords. It's like this:

- My first item

  - title:my_title
  - description:my_description (long, few hundreds words)
  - keyword1:my_keyword1
  - keywordx:my_keywordx

And I want a lot of items like this. For example 100 or 1000.

And after in code I want to make search function to look for specific items (as result may be a few, not only one) based on keywords and show the result as text in TextView field for example.

Do You have any idea how I should storage this data? I would prefer .xml file (person who will create data is not a programmer, it'll be much easier for him).

Comment: you can use sqlite for that. store your data in a database and put your database file in `assets` folder of your project and use it in your app.

Comment: Create one data type class with array list and then define one search method inside the class to search for the keyword which would return the required data

Comment: Okey, thanks. I'll read more about assets.

Comment: I find JSON files good for this sort of thing. Java gives good support fro reading and writing JSON objects.

Answer (score 0):

Put your data in JSON format as a text file, create a "res" folder, and put that text file in there. From the "your activity", read this file from the raw folder and parse the JSON.